# transform the list into a dictionary with items

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
List1 = ["1-Delphinia-65.61.138.207", 
"2-Lennie-74.37.240.220", 
"3-Shayne-174.76.131.156", 
"4-Veriee-59.20.115.49", 
"5-Val-172.101.94.229", 
"6-Lanny-1.16.47.151", 
"7-Laureen-117.2.197.11", 
"8-Kristyn-63.21.195.62", 
"9-Arlana-92.84.0.112", 
"10-Arney-49.145.219.15"]
```

Transform the list into a dictionary with items in the following format

```
{
    “Delphine” : {
        “id” : 1,
        “Ipaddr”: 65.61.138.207
    },
    “Lennie” : { ……. }, 
…….
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary comperhension:

```
>>> {name: {'id': int(id_), 'Ipaddr': ipaddr} for id_, name, ipaddr in map(lambda s: s.split('-'), List1)}
{'Delphinia': {'id': 1, 'Ipaddr': '65.61.138.207'},
 'Lennie': {'id': 2, 'Ipaddr': '74.37.240.220'},
 'Shayne': {'id': 3, 'Ipaddr': '174.76.131.156'},
 'Veriee': {'id': 4, 'Ipaddr': '59.20.115.49'},
 'Val': {'id': 5, 'Ipaddr': '172.101.94.229'},
 'Lanny': {'id': 6, 'Ipaddr': '1.16.47.151'},
 'Laureen': {'id': 7, 'Ipaddr': '117.2.197.11'},
 'Kristyn': {'id': 8, 'Ipaddr': '63.21.195.62'},
 'Arlana': {'id': 9, 'Ipaddr': '92.84.0.112'},
 'Arney': {'id': 10, 'Ipaddr': '49.145.219.15'}}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are just an assignment with no effort. This question is one several that the OP has posted, in the exact same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Other approach, using a dictionary comprehension:

```
{name: {'id': ID, 'Ipaddr': ip} for s in List1 for ID, name, ip in [s.split('-')]}
```

output:

```
{'Delphinia': {'id': '1', 'Ipaddr': '65.61.138.207'},
 'Lennie': {'id': '2', 'Ipaddr': '74.37.240.220'},
 'Shayne': {'id': '3', 'Ipaddr': '174.76.131.156'},
 'Veriee': {'id': '4', 'Ipaddr': '59.20.115.49'},
 'Val': {'id': '5', 'Ipaddr': '172.101.94.229'},
 'Lanny': {'id': '6', 'Ipaddr': '1.16.47.151'},
 'Laureen': {'id': '7', 'Ipaddr': '117.2.197.11'},
 'Kristyn': {'id': '8', 'Ipaddr': '63.21.195.62'},
 'Arlana': {'id': '9', 'Ipaddr': '92.84.0.112'},
 'Arney': {'id': '10', 'Ipaddr': '49.145.219.15'}}
```

Comment: FYI  This question is one of several that the OP has posted, in the exact same fashion. Always just their assignment, never with any work shown.

Comment: @David I had not seen this. Were other questions removed? I only see two.

Comment: Yup - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534866/parsing-and-transforming-data#comment128136191_72534866). This seems to be a pattern the OP is following.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code:

```
    List1 = ["1-Delphinia-65.61.138.207", "2-Lennie-74.37.240.220", "3-Shayne-174.76.131.156", "4-Veriee-59.20.115.49", "5-Val-172.101.94.229", "6-Lanny-1.16.47.151", "7-Laureen-117.2.197.11", "8-Kristyn-63.21.195.62", "9-Arlana-92.84.0.112", "10-Arney-49.145.219.15"]


final_dict = {}
for item in List1:
    data = item.split('-')

    final_dict[data[1]] = {'id':int(data[0]), 'Ipaddr': data[2]}

print(final_dict)
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are just an assignment with no effort. This question is one several that the OP has posted, in the exact same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def Convert(lst):
    res_dct = {lst[i+1]: {"id":lst[i],"Ipaddr":lst[i + 2]} for i in range(0,len(lst), 3)}
    return res_dct

 final_dict ={}
 for i in list1:
     l =(i.split('-'))
     new = Convert(l)
     final_dict.update(new)

output >> final_dict
{'Delphinia': {'id': '1', 'Ipaddr': '65.61.138.207'},
 'Lennie': {'id': '2', 'Ipaddr': '74.37.240.220'},
 'Shayne': {'id': '3', 'Ipaddr': '174.76.131.156'},
 'Veriee': {'id': '4', 'Ipaddr': '59.20.115.49'},
 'Val': {'id': '5', 'Ipaddr': '172.101.94.229'},
 'Lanny': {'id': '6', 'Ipaddr': '1.16.47.151'},
 'Laureen': {'id': '7', 'Ipaddr': '117.2.197.11'},
 'Kristyn': {'id': '8', 'Ipaddr': '63.21.195.62'},
 'Arlana': {'id': '9', 'Ipaddr': '92.84.0.112'},
 'Arney': {'id': '10', 'Ipaddr': '49.145.219.15'}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it with my basic python knowledge

```
new_dict= {}
for item in List1:
  newitem=item.split("-")
  new_dict[newitem[1]]={'id':int(newitem[0]),'ip':newitem[2]}
print(new_dict)
```

Output is

```
{
  "Delphinia":{
    "id":1,
    "ip":"65.61.138.207"
  },
  "Lennie":{
    "id":2,
    "ip":"74.37.240.220"
  },
  "Shayne":{
    "id":3,
    "ip":"174.76.131.156"
  },
  "Veriee":{
    "id":4,
    "ip":"59.20.115.49"
  },
  "Val":{
    "id":5,
    "ip":"172.101.94.229"
  },
  "Lanny":{
    "id":6,
    "ip":"1.16.47.151"
  },
  "Laureen":{
    "id":7,
    "ip":"117.2.197.11"
  },
  "Kristyn":{
    "id":8,
    "ip":"63.21.195.62"
  },
  "Arlana":{
    "id":9,
    "ip":"92.84.0.112"
  },
  "Arney":{
    "id":10,
    "ip":"49.145.219.15"
  }
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use `dict` as the variable name, which will override the initializer of class `dict`.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are just an assignment with no effort. This question is one several that the OP has posted, in the exact same fashion.